# Heroku error due to an already removed folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy Heroku but I still have same error:

```
    rake aborted!
    remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after ".../sass-lang.com/": expected "{", was ""
remote:        /tmp/build_fa42ee7d4fc8aec796bb9d2efab757a3/app/assets/stylesheets/todo_tasks.scss:4
```

I have removed todo_tasks.scss, it is no longer in the app on github but still I have this error,
I tried even installing heroku one more time ^^

What should I do?

Comment: There is a systax error in one of your `sass` files (probably in `stylesheets/todo_tasks.scss`). Find and fix it. Or post the content of there file into your question.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. So, thee was a bug, I fixed it but Heroku still "didn't see" that it was fixed. Then I removed the folder from my app but still Heroku shows the error that is in a removed file. Like it does not see that app has been updated...

Comment: It seems like you have to clean cache: `heroku run bash` and then `Rails.cache.clear`